# Override Attributes with Wrapper cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I just started to use Chef and want to install Hadoop on my node. So far I've got this very easy recipe which is not working.

```
my-hadoop/attributes/default.rb:

    default['hadoop']['core_site']['fs.defaultFS'] = "Test"


my-hadoop/recipes/default.rb:

    include_recipe "hadoop"

hadoop_cookbook/attributes/default.rb:

    default['hadoop']['core_site']['fs.defaultFS'] = "hdfs://#{node['fqdn']}"
```

This was my understanding of wrapper cookbooks after reading some blog posts. It is installing Hadoop but the default value is being used every time. Changing default to any other priority like 'override' doesn't solve the issue.

EDIT: The node's runlist is only 'recipe[slave]':

```
slave/recipes/default:

    include_recipe "my-hadoop"
```

Comment: What is your node runlist ? I see nothing wrong in your exemple, so maybe the runlist is problematic. You should have a depends hadoop_cookbook in my-hadoop metadata.rb and no hadoop_cookbook in the runlist.

Comment: @Tensibai: I added some information on that to the question

Comment: Sorry to ask for something more again, but when you run chef it shows you the cookbook loading at startup, for the precedence to work you should see hadopp_cookbook then my-haddop and then slave, is it the case ? Looking at how the hadoop_cokboko is done don't give a clue on why you don't get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chef 11 requires dependencies to be set in your `metadata.rb` file](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3820). `include_recipe` really only includes the recipe file so the Chef run needs some hints as to what order to load the required cookbooks in.

Your `slave` cookbook will depend on `my-hadoop`. Then `my-hadoop` will depend on `hadoop_cookbook`

File `slave/metadata.rb`:

```
depends "my-hadoop", "~> 1.5"
```

File `my-hadoop/metadata.rb`:

```
depends "hadoop_cookbook", "~> 1.3"
```

If you had set the default attribute in the `slave` cookbook, I believe it would have just worked.

Comment: My dependency files were messed up, thanks for the hint